# Scan the Application during the installation process in android

Tags: android

i just want an application that would scan the installing application and decide whether to deny the installation process or not basing upon the package name ?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Malware authors would really like it if they could block other applications from being installed.

Comment: By using PACKAGE_ADDED intent we can know the application added or not but its the intent by that time the application gets successfully installed in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an application which self-checks for integrity?
Or an application which check ANY other new application?

On the former, I would suggest to put some piece of code on the main activity which checks this. But if you are trying to have some sort of 'anti-hacking' feature it would be quite pointless, as it would simply be needed to remove those lines.

On the latter, that would be more complicated and, also, how would you know the 'correct' package name?

Comment: i just wanted to develop a anti malware sort of application.... which scans the other application that are getting installed in mobile during the installation itself....

Answer (score 0):

Third party security applications such as Lookout, McAfee, Avast, etc. run with the same limited permissions and capabilities as any other Android application.  That said, it's not possible for any Android application to "man-in-the-middle" an application installation process for security checks or any other purpose.  As mentioned by others, this would have negative security implications, as it would allow any application to modify or deny the installation of other apps.

As a third party app, the best you can do is to monitor installed packages using a broadcast receiver that listens for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED intents, or use FileObserver to trigger a security review once the app is written to the file system.  At this point if you detected an application you wanted to uninstall, you would still have to ask the user for their approval to uninstall the application.

FWIW, device manufacturers have the capability to make low-level modification to provide this capability, but I assume this is out of scope for your case.